# Two Header Rows in Datasheet View

Tags: list-view, view, datasheet

Is it possible to have two header rows?  Example, one row is the title and the one below is the description.

OR

In the Column properties, can we add the Description as the 2nd row of the Datasheet View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

This is not possible using SharePoint OOTB functionalities for Datasheet view.

However you can add description to your fields from field/column settings. These descriptions will be shown on SharePoint list forms.

Comment: Thank you @ganesh-sanap.  Is it possible to have the description show up when a user mouse over the header row rather than the title?  Or again, no OOTB, you would have to use javascript?

Comment: I am Afraid..But there is No OOTB way to do this either. But you can use JSLink to modify such things...maybe using html attributes like `title="Header Description"` on header values...Just Hint

Comment: Thank you @ganesh-sanap.  After researching last night, what I have found is that other folk's conclusion is the same as yours.  I'll count this as an answered post.  Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: welcome. please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you. And feel free to ask other questions to community on sharepoint stackexchange.

Comment: My reputation has not reached 15 yet so I can't upvote, but I did mark it as answered.